# Joomla 2.5 Backend login, frontend edit articles

Tags: authentication, joomla, admin

When i log in with my admin credentials on the frontend on Joomla, i see a nice edit icon on all of my pages. But when i only login as administrator in the backend, i dont see that nice edit icons (I can only edit through the article manager). I have to login (again) on the website itself.

Is it possible that when i log in in the backend to see those icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless there is a plugin out there somewhere.  It's by design....the nice icons are there for the convenience of non-technical/non-administrators.  The backend generally exists for altogether different reasons (config, setup, etc.), so it's not geared towards the author/editor type of user.